# How should I represent data for effective searching and comparing strings

Tags: javascript, performance, data-structures

I have two array with length 300. They look like this (JSON representation):

```
[
    [
        ["word1",0.000199],
        ["word2",0.000102],
          ...
        ["word15",0.000102]
    ],
      ...
    [
        ["anotherword1",0.0032199],
        ["anotherword2",0.032302],
          ...
        ["anotherword15",0.0320102]
    ]
]
```

And I have this bruteforce algorithm:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < 15; j++)
        {
            for(var ii = i + 1; ii < 300; ii++)
            {
                for(var jj = 0; jj < 15; jj++)
                {
                    for(var jjj = 0; jjj < 15; jjj++)
                    {
                        if(new_keywords[i][j][0] === new_keywords[ii][jj][0] && new_keywords[ii][jj][0] === state_keywords[i][jjj][0])
                        {
                            console.log(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I need to search for same words in those arrays and if words are the same, then I sum values and divide sum by 3 and replace that value in state_keywords array. So for each word which is more then once in array I have means of its values.

Now... my approach is very bad because I have now about 300 mil iterations and that is crazy. I need some better implementation of my array in JavaScript. Something like lexikographical tree or kd-tree or something.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Here is http://jsfiddle.net/dD7yB/1/ with example.

**EDIT2:**

I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough. So what exaclty I'm doing:

- I have array `state_keywords`. Indexes are from 0 to 299 and they representing a `themes`...
- Each theme may be represented by 15 words and every time `new_keywords` array arrives, they may be different.
- When new_keywords array arrive I need to check every word in that array if it is in `state_keywords` array on same theme index.
- If it is: add probabilities up and divide by 2.
- If it is not: add new word into state_keyword array BUT if they are more than 15 words for one theme (which now are) I need to store just first 15 sorted by probabilities.

And this I need to do as effectively as possbile, because I need to do this every second so it must be FAST.

**EDIT3:**

Now I use this code:

```
var i, j, jj, l;
for(i = 0; i < 300; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 15; j++)
    {
        l = new_keywords[i].length;
        for(jj = 0; jj < l; jj++)
        {
            if(state_keywords[i][j][0] === new_keywords[i][jj][0])
            {  
                state_keywords[i][j][1] = (state_keywords[i][j][1] + new_keywords[i][jj][1]) / 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which is much faster then the previous one.

Comment: what is "state_keywords" array ?

Comment: @Adidi state_keywords is array where I represent mean probabilities for words stored in those arrays. The words may change and I need always to store words with highest probabilities. I don't want to simply replace `state_keywords` array with `new_keywords.`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you make those arrays into objects with the strings as keys to the values?  Then you can just just look up the words directly and get the values?

```
var wordlists = [
    {
        "word1":0.000199,
        "word2":0.000102,
          ...
        "word15":0.000102
    },
      ...
    {
        "anotherword1":0.0032199,
        "anotherword2":0.032302,
          ...
        "anotherword15":0.0320102
    }
]
```

and then lookup with

```
wordlists[0]["word2"]  //0.000102
```